# How to sed replace text block

Tags: sed

There is a aa.txt containing the following lines

```
security.provider.1=com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2
security.provider.2=com.ibm.crypto.provider.IBMJCE
security.provider.3=com.ibm.security.jgss.IBMJGSSProvider
security.provider.4=com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPath
security.provider.5=com.ibm.security.sasl.IBMSASL
security.provider.6=com.ibm.xml.crypto.IBMXMLCryptoProvider
```

Then I want to replace them with the following

```
security.provider.1=com.ibm.crypto.plus.provider.IBMJCEPlusFIPS
security.provider.2=com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2
security.provider.3=com.ibm.crypto.provider.IBMJCE
security.provider.4=com.ibm.crypto.plus.provider.IBMJCEPlus
security.provider.5=com.ibm.security.jgss.IBMJGSSProvider
security.provider.6=com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPath
security.provider.7=com.ibm.security.sasl.IBMSASL
security.provider.8=com.ibm.xml.crypto.IBMXMLCryptoProvider
security.provider.9=com.ibm.xml.enc.IBMXMLEncProvider
security.provider.10=com.ibm.security.jgss.mech.spnego.IBMSPNEGO
security.provider.11=sun.security.provider.Sun
```

I use sed command to do that

```
sed -i -e "/^security\.provider\.1=.*/,/^security\.provider\.6.*/{/^security\.provider\.6}.*/{to be done}" aa.txt
```

I could not figure out the part of "to be done", could anybody point out how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts. Could you please do mention logic of getting your expected output also in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store replacement block in a file called `repl.txt` as:

```sh
cat repl.txt

security.provider.1=com.ibm.crypto.plus.provider.IBMJCEPlusFIPS
security.provider.2=com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2
security.provider.3=com.ibm.crypto.provider.IBMJCE
security.provider.4=com.ibm.crypto.plus.provider.IBMJCEPlus
security.provider.5=com.ibm.security.jgss.IBMJGSSProvider
security.provider.6=com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPath
security.provider.7=com.ibm.security.sasl.IBMSASL
security.provider.8=com.ibm.xml.crypto.IBMXMLCryptoProvider
security.provider.9=com.ibm.xml.enc.IBMXMLEncProvider
security.provider.10=com.ibm.security.jgss.mech.spnego.IBMSPNEGO
security.provider.11=sun.security.provider.Sun
```

Then search and replace using:

```sh
sed '/^security\.provider\.1=.*/,/^security\.provider\.6.*/{
/^security\.provider\.1/!d
r repl.txt
//d
}' inputfile
```

---

To avoid using a file to hold replacement use:

```sh
sed '/^security\.provider\.1=.*/,/^security\.provider\.6.*/{
/^security\.provider\.1/!d
a\
security.provider.1=com.ibm.crypto.plus.provider.IBMJCEPlusFIPS\
security.provider.2=com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2\
security.provider.3=com.ibm.crypto.provider.IBMJCE\
security.provider.4=com.ibm.crypto.plus.provider.IBMJCEPlus\
security.provider.5=com.ibm.security.jgss.IBMJGSSProvider\
security.provider.6=com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPath\
security.provider.7=com.ibm.security.sasl.IBMSASL\
security.provider.8=com.ibm.xml.crypto.IBMXMLCryptoProvider\
security.provider.9=com.ibm.xml.enc.IBMXMLEncProvider\
security.provider.10=com.ibm.security.jgss.mech.spnego.IBMSPNEGO\
security.provider.11=sun.security.provider.Sun
//d
}' file
```

Comment: Please see my test result. Could you point out what does "!d" and "//d"?

Comment: in your test case, you create a repl.txt, it works well. However, I want to use a variable to replace repl.txt, it doesn't work. Any idea to replace repl.txt file with an string variable?

Comment: you cannot use a variable here because there are newlines and there might be special characters.

Comment: could you give a sed link of explaining d/r/...? I would like to learn what it mean and how to use them? For my case, I have to replace repl.txt in my system.

Comment: You have to include sample input and expected output in your question. For sed I would just suggest take a look at `man sed`

Comment: For new line, could we add \n to represent it?

Comment: I have added an answer that works without using `repl.txt`